# Difficulties connecting to socket.io server with Ionic

Tags: node.js, web-services, cordova, ionic-framework, socket.io

An overview of my setup:

A socket.io/node server is being hosted/ran on a computer in my local network. 
An Ionic app is attempting to connect to the socket.io/node server to send/receive messages.

If I run the app in the browser with 'ionic serve', I am able to connect to the socket.io/node server successfully.

If I run the app in the emulator or on my device, I am only able to connect to the socket.io/node server if I add the -l (livereload) flag (ionic run android -l).

Originally, I hosted the node server on a heroku instance. I had no troubles connecting with this setup from browser, phone, or emulator. I had to switch to running the node server on a local computer so I have access to a local database.

Any ideas what is going on?

Comment: Try using this flag with ionic serve `--address localhost`

Comment: That works, but it also works without that flag. i'm not having trouble connecting on the browser, I'm having trouble connecting with the emulator and device.

Comment: Also, the server is not running on my computer, it's running on another computer in my network.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by adding 'http://' to the beginning of the connection string.

Not sure why Ionic's livereload enabled me to connect without the 'http'